# Incorrect IK behaviours

Tags: rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

I am rigging a robot for some personal training, and I got into a very weird issue while rigging the legs.

[image]

Here are my two foots, both are parented to the right bones, rigged to their respective Target and all this stuff. But one is acting like if it was parented to the target, while the other reacts like if it was just copying the Target's rotation (which is what I want the other to do).

I double checked all possible parameters that could cause this on each bones of both legs, and I'm still unable to explain why this is happening and how to fix it...

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a blend file with your problem (should just need the armature, not the model) to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add it to your post? Without being able to inspect what you have done its hard to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Added it, I hope it clarifies my problem's nature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your upper leg bones.

On the bone properties tab under inverse kinematics, there are the settings for bending limits and stiffness that are used by the IK solver to calculate the end positions/rotations for the bones.

Your left upper leg has different settings than the right here.

Comment: ohhhh yeah I actually forgot to check those.
I didn't expected them to cause this kind of troubles...
only disabling the Y axis seems to give the result I want !